# 2000s SF series about exploration and escaping from dangers, including a humanoid bird species

Tags: story-identification, books

I believe I read these books in 2000s.

Main character: a female named something like Linda.

In one of the series (maybe just two books), there is a science team exploring new worlds.  They found a humanoid bird species and think these angel-like creatures are civilized.  They only find out their errors when these predator birds attacked and killed a couple of them.   There are also other explorations.   They do not need to wear space suit.  Some sort of force field from their belt is enough to provide environment protection.  However, it's not strong enough to protect them from sharp objects such as claws and beaks.

Another book involves with the boarding and exploration of a huge alien ship that has something like a zoo or animal exhibition inside.  The story ends with the female hero piloting a small spacecraft and shooting passed the alien spaceship to pick up her future fiance.

Last book is about their exploration of a world that suddenly is in danger of destruction.  The explorers have to climb a huge mountain to be picked up by sort of space elevator/spacecraft combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be "Priscilla" instead of Linda? Because it reminds me of the [Jack McDevitt series about her](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11456).

- In [Chindi](https://sciencefictionhyperdrive.blogspot.com/2011/07/review-of-chindi-by-jack-mcdevitt.html) the party is attacked by "a species of avian beings who look beautiful but are really savages"
- In [Deepsix](https://sciencefictionhyperdrive.blogspot.com/2011/05/review-of-deepsix-by-jack-mcdevitt.html) they end up escaping the doomed planet by a skyhook / spaceship combination.

I don't know the one about the zoo but I haven't read them all.

Comment: I agree.  These are the Priscilla Hutchins stories. The huge collector starship in Chindi has zoo-like samples from many worlds.

Comment: You are correct!   Those were Deepsix and Chindi.  The zoo spacecraft is actually the 16 km long asteroid ship in Chindi.